# How do i get my app on the location services list?

Tags: ios, settings, cllocationmanager

I am developing a CLLocation app.
In some rare cases the app doesn't start the compass.

I expect the problem lies with location services.

How do i get my app on the location services settings list?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there automatically.  Your problem is not that you aren't appearing on the list, your problem is:

> In some rare cases the app doesn't start the compass.

I suggest you post a question about that, including information on the circumstances under which this happens, the code you are using, and any other relevant information.

Comment: Even on those devices where the app does work i never get to see it on the list nor do i get a prompt, asking for permission.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in the list even in cases where the app does work, then clearly not appearing in the list isn't the direct cause of the problem.